# Show & Hide UIImageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've implemented the following code & it's getting built and running successfully but the issue I'm facing is it's not hiding the **ImageView** in the first **TableViewCell**

[image: Issue/Bug Image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! VPSScreenTableViewCell
    
      cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: iconImage[indexPath.row])
      cell.titleLabel.text = heading[indexPath.row]
      cell.subLabel.text = subHeading[indexPath.row]
    cell.buttonImgView.image = UIImage(named: buttonImage[indexPath.row])
   
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.verifiedImageView.isHidden == true
    } else {
            cell.verifiedImageView.isHidden == false
         cell.verifiedImageView.image = UIImage(named: verificationImage[indexPath.row])
    }
   return cell
     
 }
```

Comment: return cell in if condition

Comment: if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.verifiedImageView.isHidden == true
              return cell
        } else {
                cell.verifiedImageView.isHidden == false
             cell.verifiedImageView.image = UIImage(named: verificationImage[indexPath.row])
        }
       return cell
         
     }
Like this ???

Comment: how ?? @OmerTekbiyik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting your `isHidden` property correctly.

You only need one `=` not two.

```
cell.verifiedImageView.isHidden = true
```

`==` is a comparator, you should have seen this compiler warning for that:

[image: Result of operator '==' is unused]

Comment: Thank You So Much :D , It's Working !

Answer (score 0):

Please update my code with your code. It will work. Your only mistake is `==` instead of `=`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! VPSScreenTableViewCell
          cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: iconImage[indexPath.row])
          cell.titleLabel.text = heading[indexPath.row]
          cell.subLabel.text = subHeading[indexPath.row]
        cell.buttonImgView.image = UIImage(named: buttonImage[indexPath.row])
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.verifiedImageView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.verifiedImageView.isHidden = false
            cell.verifiedImageView.image = UIImage(named: verificationImage[indexPath.row])
        }
       return cell
     }
```